# Kafka Java Consumer API Issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to consume message using  Kafka java API. am able to consume message using kafka-console-consumer.bat. But, not able consume message from java api. not getting any error or any message. help me what mistake am doing.

```
import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SimpleConsumer {
    private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private final String topic;

    public SimpleConsumer(String zookeeper, String groupId, String topic) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper);
        props.put("group.id", groupId);
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "500");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "250");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");

        consumer = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(props));
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public void testConsumer() {
        Map<String, Integer> topicCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCount.put(topic, 1);
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerStreams = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCount);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerStreams.get(topic);
        for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
            ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("Message from Single Topic: " + new String(it.next().message()));
            }
        }
        if (consumer != null) {
            consumer.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String topic = "test";
        SimpleConsumer simpleHLConsumer = new SimpleConsumer("localhost:2181", "testgroup", topic);
        simpleHLConsumer.testConsumer();
    }
}
```

**Console command**

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

created topic:

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic test
```

publish message using:

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

if I run consumer program, getting log in Broker console:

> [2015-12-29 11:57:34,448] INFO Closing socket connection to /IP (kafka.network.Processor).

if I close the program getting this log:

> java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Please help me why I am not able to consume message from above program.

But, able to consume message using

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Help me.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to read messages from the beginning you need to set option

```
auto.offset.reset=smallest
```

it's 'largest' by default.

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

> What to do when there is no initial offset in ZooKeeper or if an
>   offset is out of range:
>
> - smallest : automatically reset the offset to the smallest offset
> - largest : automatically reset the offset to the largest offset
> - anything else: throw exception to the consumer

NOTE: this option for new consumer API(since 0.9.0.0):

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest|latest|none
```

Offsets have been saved in zookeeper for your group.id. So if you want to see messages change group.id or cleanup zookeeper

Comment: Thanks for your information. Even after applying props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest"); . I am not able to consume message from test topic. please let me know where is the issue ?

Comment: have you changed group.id?

Comment: I have changed groupId to testgroup2. But consumer is not able to consume message. posting message using BAT kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test. Please help me.

Comment: Created topic using this command **kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic test**

Comment: Getting below log in Broker console when run the java consumer program. **[2015-12-29 11:57:34,448] INFO Closing socket connection to /IP. (kafka.network.Processor)
[2015-12-29 11:57:34,558] ERROR Closing socket for /IP because of error (kafka.network.Processor)**

Comment: what version of kafka and client library do you use?

Comment: Thanks. After changing my POM.XML dependency version. it works good

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka_2.9.1</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.2.2</version>
  </dependency>